# Initialize an array like this pass2[2]="aa"; does not work

Tags: c, arrays, hash, cs50

I am working on an assignment in which I have to crack a DES-based hashed password.
The user inputs the hashed password in the command line argument; I hash every possibility (assuming **salt is 50**, pass is **no longer than 4 characters** and **characters can be abc...xyz and ABC...XYZ**); when my hash and the hashed in the command line are equal, I print the unhashed password.

With passwords 1 character long everything works, but I am having some trouble with passwords 2 characters long. *I want this question to be short and don't overwhelm you, so I will post my entire code at the really end, should you want to see it*.

**So**, I have this line with the possible characters the password might consist of:

```
string options="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

and then I build the possible password. 
I take a first character from options and store it in the position [0] of variable `pass2` (at this point, pass2='a'). Then I do the same for position [1] as many times as there are options (which stores the second value of pass2 --> pass2='aa'..'aZ'). If none of those options are the pasword I am trying to find, I carry on with the first character again (pass2='bZ') and go ahed trying and trying with different options of position [1] (pass2='ba')... and so on. The code:

```
char pass2[0][1] = "aa";
for (int j=0, n=strlen(options); j<n; j++)
{
    pass2[0]=options[j];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pass2[1]=options[i];
        string hash2=crypt(pass2, "50");
        if (memcmp(hash2, argv[1], 13)==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", pass2);
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above, I want my program to take the variable `pass2` and store the following: aa, ab, ac,..., aX, aY, aZ,..., Za, Zb, Zc,..., ZX, ZY, ZZ. And when I read the code, it MAKES SENSE TO ME. (I have zero experience, but I really feel like this time I wrote something coherent that should work).

However, it does not. That makes me think that there might be some problems with the way I wrote/declared/initialized some stuff. Also, the following error code supports that thought:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list
    char pass2[][1] = "ab";
```

If someone realizes what the problem is, please tell me, because I have tried all the possible ways to delcare an array I found on this [answer](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/a/1085), and I still get the error. Well, even when I don't get an error message it does not work, so any solution will be welcome.

**Thank you all!**

As I said before, here is my full code in case someone wants to check it:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    if (argc!=2){
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string options="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char pass1[]="A";
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(options); i<n; i++)
    {
        pass1[0]=options[i];
        string hash1=crypt(pass1, "50");
        if (memcmp(hash1, argv[1], 13)==0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", options[i]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    char pass2[0][1] = "aa";
    for (int j=0, n=strlen(options); j<n; j++)
    {
        pass2[0]=options[j];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            pass2[1]=options[i];
        }

        string hash2=crypt(pass2, "50");
        if (memcmp(hash2, argv[1], 13)==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", pass2);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't *assign* to an array, only initialize it or *copy* to it.

Comment: Furthermore, in C a `char` string is really called ***null-terminated*** *byte strings*. That *null-termination* is important, as all string functions look for the null *character* (as opposed to the null pointer) `'\0'` to find the end of the string. That of course means that a string of e.g. one characters needs space for *two* characters to be able to fit the terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thank you all who answered.
Here is the way I solved it. Where I used to write this:

```
char pass2[0][1] = "aa";
for (int j=0, n=strlen(options); j<n; j++)
{
    pass2[0]=options[j];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pass2[1]=options[i];
    }

    string hash2=crypt(pass2, "50");
    if (memcmp(hash2, argv[1], 13)==0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pass2);
    }
}
```

and take a special look at

```
char pass2[0][1] =="aa";
```

I write now this:

```
char pass2[3] = "aa";
```

As I said when asking, to declare the variables-arrays (I am still trying to figure out which one is it), I was following the guides I found [here](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/a/1085); and though apparently I was declaring the array* right (specifying the lenght within the brackets), I forgot there was the null-terminator (the answer by kuroi neko made me think about it). What means that, when I wrote `char pass2[2] = "aa"` and it didn't work, I tought it was because of the syntax -or the way of delcaring/initializing it-, but it actually was me forgetting about the third character "\0", which means it should have always been written like this: `char pass2[3] = "aa"`.

This is the... **my** solution, `char pass2[3] = "aa"`.
In case you want to check the full code, here it is: **THANKS AGAIN!**

```
    #define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    if (argc!=2){
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string options="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char pass1[]="A";
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(options); i<n; i++)
    {
        pass1[0]=options[i];
        string hash1=crypt(pass1, "50");
        if (memcmp(hash1, argv[1], 13)==0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", options[i]);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    char pass2[3]= "aa";
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(options); i<n; i++)
    {
        pass2[0]=options[i];
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            pass2[1]=options[j];
            string hash2=crypt(pass2, "50");
            if (memcmp(hash2, argv[1], 13)==0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", pass2);
                return 0;
            }
        }


    }

    char pass3[4]= "aaa";
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(options); i<n; i++)
    {
        pass3[0]=options[i];
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            pass3[1]=options[j];
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                pass3[2]=options[k];
                string hash3=crypt(pass3, "50");
                if (memcmp(hash3, argv[1], 13)==0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", pass3);
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    char pass4[5]= "aaaa";
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(options); i<n; i++)
    {
        pass4[0]=options[i];
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            pass4[1]=options[j];
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                pass4[2]=options[k];
                for (int l=0; l<n; l++)
                {
                    pass4[3]=options[l];
                    string hash4=crypt(pass4, "50");
                    if (memcmp(hash4, argv[1], 13)==0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", pass4);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a lot of time and trouble (and external help) to finish the program, so I am proud and confident it is the best I can do yet. I feel, I could trust someone who told me there is a better solution. There actually might be a more efficient solution. But I have been programming for two weeks now, so this is kind of the most efficient code I can write **and** understand. Bear with me.

Comment: `if (memcmp(hash1, argv[1], 13)==0)` is a problem should `hash1` or `argv[1]` point to memory less than 13 `char`.

Comment: `char pass2[3]= "aa";` is followed by 2 `for` loops - OK. `char pass3[4]= "aaa";` is followed by 4 `for` loops when 3 expected.  `pass3[3]=options[l];` and `pass4[4]=options[m];` lead to UB like buffer overruns.

Comment: hey @chux , you are completely right!! Regarding your first comment, I run crypt() with various salts and keys and realized it always returned a hash 13 char long, so I don't know how could hash1 or argv[1] be different from 13. (This was a school assignment, so we assumed user input would be a real hash; of course though, in real life someone might just input other stuff..). 
About the `for` loops: wow, you saw that(!); thanks a lot because I didn't and that did create a problem, the CPU was super high, IDE platform froze... well. Thank you!

Comment: "we assumed user input would be a real hash" --> validate user input - it is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding what C arrays really are is not easy at first. Trouble is, the bracket notation `[]` creates all kinds of confusions between pointers and arrays.

Here what you need is an array able to hold the biggest possible password candidate. Since it is limited to 4 characters and C strings must have a terminating `\0` character, you will need 5 bytes at most.

Then you will have to intialize this candidate string with all possible combinations if 1 to 4 letters, which is a classic combinatorics problem.

It is equivalent to enumerating all numbers of n digits in base 52 (all possible characters), or counting from 0 to 52<sup>n</sup>-1 in base 52, with n between 1 and 4.

A loop that would generate all possible password candidates would look like this:

```
// despite the array notation, this is a pointer to a constant string of 53 chars
// (including the automatically generated terminating \0)
char Letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
#define ALPHABET_SIZE 52
#define MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH 4

void try_password (long enumerator, int length)
{
    // this is an actual array that can hold 4 chars plus the \0 terminator
    char candidate[MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1]; 
    int i;

    // convert the enumerator into a base 52 number
    // (will be written in reverse order, but in that case we don't care)
    for (i = 0 ; i != length ; i++)
    {
        candidate[i] = Letters[enumerator%ALPHABET_SIZE];
        enumerator /= ALPHABET_SIZE;
    }
    candidate[i] = '\0'; // add string terminator

    // check password candidate
    if (check_password (candidate))
    {
        printf ("Yay! %s\n", candidate);
    }
}

void try_fixed_length_passwords (int length)
{
    long enumerator = 1; // must be big enough to hold 52^^4 - 1 (>= 24 bits)
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i != length ; i++) enumerator *= ALPHABET_SIZE;
    // now enumerator = 52^^length
    // you could also use math.h and compute enumerator = (long)pow(52,length)

    // enumerate all password candidates of a given length
    while (enumerator != 0)
    {
        enumerator--; /// will count from 52^^lenght-1 to 0
        try_password (enumerator, length);
    }
}

void try_all_passwords (void)
{
    // try all possible password lengths
    int i;
    for (i = 1 ; i <= MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH ; i++) try_fixed_length_passwords(i);
}
```

Comment: Kuroi, I cannot expres how grateful I am that you took all this trouble to help me. I do feel like your solution is a thousand times better than mine, and you try to teach me some good stuff, I can feel that. I actually reached my solution thanks to something you said (about the \0). However, I could not use your solution, even guessing (not actually realizing) how good it was, because I do not understand it. I hate myself for saying this, given **all** the notes you left me, but there are so many things that I don't get. I'm just too ignorant yet programming, for such a good answer. Sorry&thx